# R: How to Create a 3D Histogram using Two Vectors?

Tags: r, 3d, histogram

I have two vectors of equal length (1000 elements each). Both of them happen to be in the same range. This is the sample of my data:

```
[895,] -1.025145319  1.024794005
[896,] -0.558025939  0.676659954
[897,]  1.386353785 -0.415513640
[898,]  0.742762961  1.173350232
```

Using these two vectors, I wish to create a 3D histogram with the values of the first vector as my X-axis and the values of the second vector at the Y-axis. The Z-axis will be the frequency of the 3D histogram. I tried implementing the hist3d function but to no luck. Is there a way I can implement this in R?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The Z-axis will be the frequency of the 3D histogram." - I'm not sure what that means, can you clarify?

Comment: What is a "frequency of the 3D histogram"?